# Adding a new firewall rule for a local user profile through GPO

Tags: powershell, windows-firewall, gpo

My company has rolled out a new softphone service that has been installed successfully through the GPO to each machine. The thing is, the software is installed in the user profile which then asks to be allowed access through windows defender firewall, and I'm having a hard time allowing that access which needs admin credentials. Variables Like %localappdata% or %userprofile% doesn't work in GPO. Startup script doesn't work, because it puts the firewall rule under the admin profile. The Logon script doesn't work because it needs admin privileges to add a new-newfirewallrule.

```
$username = $env:username

New-NetFirewallRule -Displayname "Five9Softphone" -Direction Inbound -Program C:\Users\$username\appdata\local\Five9\Five9Softphone-10.0\bin\10.2.16\five9softphone.exe
```

This works when running with any admin users but not my normal users. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run something like the following:

```
$profiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users' -Directory
Foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
    $ExePath = Join-Path -Path $profile.Fullname -ChildPath 'appdata\local\Five9\Five9Softphone-10.0\bin\10.2.16\five9softphone.exe'
    if (!(Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter -Program $ExePath)) {
        New-NetFirewallRule -Displayname "Five9Softphone" -Direction Inbound -Program $ExePath
    }
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Is there any way to get the newest user? If I do as you say it works but some workstations have a lot of users and it fills up the whole firewall sheet with old users. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! Thank you for your help